# Recommended way to wrap C lib initialization/destruction routine

Tags: rust

I am writing a wrapper/FFI for a C library that requires a global initialization call in the main thread as well as one for destruction.

Here is how I am currently handling it:

```
struct App;

impl App {
    fn init() -> Self {
        unsafe { ffi::InitializeMyCLib(); }
        App
    }
}

impl Drop for App {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        unsafe { ffi::DestroyMyCLib(); }
    }
}
```

which can be used like:

```
fn main() {
    let _init_ = App::init();
    // ...
}
```

This works fine, but it feels like a hack, tying these calls to the lifetime of an unnecessary struct. Having the destructor in a `finally` (Java) or `at_exit` (Ruby) block seems theoretically more appropriate.

Is there some more graceful way to do this in Rust?

**EDIT**

Would it be possible/safe to use this setup like so (using the `lazy_static` crate), instead of my second block above:

```
lazy_static! {
    static ref APP: App = App::new();
}
```

Would this reference be guaranteed to be initialized before any other code and destroyed on exit? Is it bad practice to use `lazy_static` in a library?

This would also make it easier to facilitate access to the FFI through this one struct, since I wouldn't have to bother passing around the reference to the instantiated struct (called `_init_` in my original example).

This would also make it safer in some ways, since I could make the `App` struct default constructor private.

Comment: Side-Note: Depending on how safe you want your wrapper to be, you should make the `init` function unsafe (because noone may call it multiple times), and implement all functions that require the clib to be initialized as methods on the `App` object. This way noone can call the functions without having it initialized. You can also implement it as some sort of reference counted singleton to make it safe to initialize. This is a big win over Java and Ruby, because there you can call the functions without having initialized the lib

Comment: *in the main thread* — are you **sure** it has to be the main thread? Could it be any thread, so long as it's initialized before use?

Comment: @ker, thanks for the comment. I hadn't thought about it like that (having all access through the `App` struct, but that makes sense. I'll have to think about whether this would work for my case.

Comment: @Shepmaster, thanks for the comment. The C library is GraphicsMagick and I am just going by the documentation: `This function should be invoked in the primary (original) thread of the application's process`. I'm a Rust beginner coming mostly from Ruby, so I don't really know about "musts" in terms of thread usage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know of no way of enforcing that a method be called in the main thread beyond strongly-worded documentation. So, ignoring that requirement... :-)

Generally, I'd use [`std::sync::Once`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Once.html), which seems basically designed for this case:

> A synchronization primitive which can be used to run a one-time global
>   initialization. Useful for one-time initialization for FFI or related
>   functionality. This type can only be constructed with the `ONCE_INIT`
>   value.

Note that there's no provision for any cleanup; many times you just have to leak whatever the library has done. Usually if a library has a dedicated cleanup path, it has also been structured to store all that initialized data in a type that is then passed into subsequent functions as some kind of context or environment. This would map nicely to Rust types.

**Warning**

Your current code is *not* as protective as you hope it is. Since your `App` is an empty struct, an end-user can construct it *without calling your method*:

```
let _init_ = App;
```

We will use a zero-sized argument to prevent this. See also [What's the Rust idiom to define a field pointing to a C opaque pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38315383/155423) for the proper way to construct opaque types for FFI.

Altogether, I'd use something like this:

```rust
use std::sync::Once;

mod ffi {
    extern "C" {
        pub fn InitializeMyCLib();
        pub fn CoolMethod(arg: u8);
    }
}

static C_LIB_INITIALIZED: Once = Once::new();

#[derive(Copy, Clone)]
struct TheLibrary(());

impl TheLibrary {
    fn new() -> Self {
        C_LIB_INITIALIZED.call_once(|| unsafe {
            ffi::InitializeMyCLib();
        });
        TheLibrary(())
    }

    fn cool_method(&self, arg: u8) {
        unsafe { ffi::CoolMethod(arg) }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let lib = TheLibrary::new();
    lib.cool_method(42);
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer! Your use of `Once` reminded me of the `lazy_static` crate. I've updated my question with another possible way of handling this, but I don't know if it is sound.

Answer (score 2):

I did some digging around to see how other FFI libs handle this situation. Here is what I am currently using (similar to @Shepmaster's answer and based loosely on the initialization routine of [curl-rust](https://github.com/carllerche/curl-rust)):

```
fn initialize() {
    static INIT: Once = ONCE_INIT;
    INIT.call_once(|| unsafe {
        ffi::InitializeMyCLib();
        assert_eq!(libc::atexit(cleanup), 0);
    });

    extern fn cleanup() {
        unsafe { ffi::DestroyMyCLib(); }
    }
}
```

I then call this function inside the public constructors for my public structs.