# What's the Rust idiom to define a field pointing to a C opaque pointer?

Tags: rust

Given a struct:

```
#[repr(C)]
pub struct User {
    pub name: *const c_char,
    pub age: u8,
    pub ctx: ??,
}
```

the field `ctx` would only be manipulated by C code; it's a pointer to a C struct `UserAttr`.

According to [the Rust FFI documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ffi.html), the choice would be defined as an opaque type `pub enum UserAttr {}`. However, I found that Rust is unable to copy its value, e.g. [why does the address of an object change across methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38302270/why-does-the-address-of-an-object-change-across-methods).

What's the right way in Rust to define such an opaque pointer, so that its value (as a pointer) gets copied across methods?

Comment: It's not that “Rust is unable to copy its value”, it's just that this is how languages such as Rust and C work. Did you read the other question's answer and specifically about `Box`?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

#### The future

[RFC 1861](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1861-extern-types.md) introduced the concept of an *extern type*. While implemented, it is not yet stabilized. Once it is, it will become the preferred implementation:

```
#![feature(extern_types)]

extern "C" {
    type Foo;
}

type FooPtr = *mut Foo;
```

#### Today

[The Rustonomicon](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/ffi.html#representing-opaque-structs) states:

> To do this in Rust, let’s create our own opaque types:
>
> ```
> #[repr(C)]
> pub struct Foo {
>     _data: [u8; 0],
>     _marker:
>         core::marker::PhantomData<(*mut u8, core::marker::PhantomPinned)>,
> }
> #[repr(C)]
> pub struct Bar {
>     _data: [u8; 0],
>     _marker:
>         core::marker::PhantomData<(*mut u8, core::marker::PhantomPinned)>,
> }
> ```
>
> By including at least one private field and no constructor,
> we create an opaque type that we can't instantiate outside of this module.
> (A struct with no field could be instantiated by anyone.)
> We also want to use this type in FFI, so we have to add `#[repr(C)]`.
> The marker ensures the compiler does not mark the struct as `Send`, `Sync` and `Unpin` are
> not applied to the struct. (`*mut u8` is not `Send` or `Sync`, `PhantomPinned` is not `Unpin`)

An opaque pointer is created such that there's no normal way of creating such a type; you can only create pointers to it.

```
mod ffi {
    use std::ptr;

    pub struct MyTypeFromC {
        _data: [u8; 0],
        _marker:
            core::marker::PhantomData<(*mut u8, core::marker::PhantomPinned)>,
    }

    pub fn constructor() -> *mut MyTypeFromC {
        ptr::null_mut()
    }

    pub fn something(_thing: *mut MyTypeFromC) {
        println!("Doing a thing");
    }
}

use ffi::*;

struct MyRustType {
    score: u8,
    the_c_thing: *mut MyTypeFromC,
}

impl MyRustType {
    fn new() -> MyRustType {
        MyRustType {
            score: 42,
            the_c_thing: constructor(),
        }
    }

    fn something(&mut self) {
        println!("My score is {}", self.score);
        ffi::something(self.the_c_thing);
        self.score += 1;
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut my_thing = MyRustType::new();
    my_thing.something();
}
```

Breaking it down a bit:

```
// opaque -----V~~~~~~~~~V
          *mut MyTypeFromC
//        ^~~^ ------------ pointer
```

Thus it's an opaque pointer. Moving the struct `MyRustType` will not change the value of the pointer.

#### The past

Previous iterations of this answer and the documentation suggested using an empty enum (`enum MyTypeFromC {}`). An enum with no variants is semantically equivalent to the never type (`!`), which is a type that cannot exist. There were concerns that using such a construct could lead to undefined behavior, so moving to an empty array was deemed safer.