# How to use a C typedef struct and functions with that struct from Rust?

Tags: rust, extern, ffi

I have these C files and I want to use `pair_add`, `add` and `PAIR` from Rust.

**adder.c**

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "adder.h"

int pair_add(PAIR * ppair) {
    return ppair->x + ppair->y;
}

int add(int x, int y) {
    return x + y;
}
```

**adder.h**

```c
typedef struct {
    int x;
    int y;
} PAIR;

int pair_add(PAIR * ppair);
int add(int, int);
```

I compile them using:

```
gcc -c adder.c
ar rc libadder.a adder.o  # Static link
```

The [documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch19-01-unsafe-rust.html#using-extern-functions-to-call-external-code) does not detail how to integrate C typedef structs and [the example](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ffi.html) is for functions which return and accept `i32`. [Other online resources were also limited](https://github.com/alexcrichton/rust-ffi-examples/blob/master/rust-to-c/src/main.rs).

I attempted the following but could not add the `PAIR` typedef:

```
extern crate libc;

use libc::c_int;

#[link(name = "adder")]
extern "C" {
    // Define PAIR

    // int pair_add(PAIR * ppair);
    fn pair_add(input: Pair) -> c_int;

    // int add(int, int);
    fn add(input1: c_int) -> c_int;
}

fn main() {}
```

Comment: @Stargateur Updated the post and posted a new question on that topic https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50619070

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First:

```c
typedef struct {
    int x;
    int y;
} PAIR;
```

This declares an anonymous struct and this is not currently supported by Rust. There is a [RFC](https://internals.rust-lang.org/t/pre-rfc-anonymous-struct-and-union-types/3894) that proposes to add anonymous types.

Secondly, a `typedef` is just an alias and the name of the struct isn't important to be compatible. That means that you can simply do:

```
extern crate libc;
use libc::c_int;

#[repr(C)]
struct PAIR {
    x: c_int,
    y: c_int,
}

// optional "equivalent" of typedef
type Pair = PAIR;

extern "C" {
    fn pair_add(input: *mut Pair) -> c_int;
    // could be
    // fn pair_add(input: *mut PAIR) -> c_int;
}
```

You could easily ignore the typedef and just use `PAIR` as a name for this struct. You can even just write `struct PAIR;` to make it opaque.

Comment: You don't need to match the struct's name to start with, you can just do `#[repr(C)] struct Pair { x: c_int, y: c_int }`. You can give it any name you want, because as you mention, the name doesn't matter to the compiler.

Comment: *to make it opaque* — I would **not** use this to define an opaque type. [Another Q&A has suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38315383/155423), but `struct PAIR;` would allow *anyone* to create an instance of a `PAIR`, which should not be allowed if it's opaque.