# What are the different ways of specifying the linking path to FFI libraries in Rust?

Tags: rust, extern, ffi

Using the below code as an example:

```
extern crate libc;

#[link(name = "adder")]
extern {
    fn double_input(input: libc::c_int) -> libc::c_int;
}

fn main() {
    let input = 4;
    let output = unsafe { double_input(input) };
    println!("{} * 2 = {}", input, output);
}
```

Should `#[link(name = "adder")]` include a relative path to the **.o / a / .h** files? For example, should it be `#[link(name = "../adderlib/adder")]`? Is there another way to tell the compiler where `adder` is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to the first question is YES! If your lib file is `libfoo.o`, `#[link(name = "foo")` is enough in your code. There are more details in the [official documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/first-edition/ffi.html).

It will be relative to the lib file which is located in the current work path and the system lib path. (I cannot find this in any documentation, but I once made it successfully). You can specify a path using `rustc -l XX -L XX`. Using Cargo with a [build script](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/build-scripts.html) is a better way.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to control how a library is found or linked to your Rust code, you should do so via a [build script](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/build-scripts.html).