# How can dynamically-sized types be expressed safely?

Tags: winapi, rust, ffi

I am writing a safe wrapper over an FFI library that uses dynamically-sized types, and I am trying to determine the best way to handle them in Rust.

In particular, I am wrapping the Windows API's [`SID`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winnt/ns-winnt-_sid) structure. It has a BYTE (`u8`) indicating the current revision, a BYTE (`u8`) indicating the number of sub-authorities, six BYTEs (`[u8; 6]`) indicating the identifier authority, and then a series of DWORDs (`u32`s) that represent the number of sub-authorities. It has as many sub-authorities as indicated by the sub-authority count.

In general, the approach is to only ever handle SIDs through WinAPI calls, so I should only ever have a pointer to it. Additionally, by keeping the internals private, I can ensure that consumers of my crate can only ever access it through a reference, `Box`, etc. that I control. However, I do need to declare *some* kind of `Sid` type, and I am trying to determine the best approach.

Option 1: The `winapi` crate just assumes that there will only be [a single sub-authority](https://docs.rs/winapi/*/x86_64-pc-windows-msvc/winapi/um/winnt/struct.SID.html):

```rust
pub struct SID {
    Revision: BYTE,
    SubAuthorityCount: BYTE,
    IdentifierAuthority: SID_IDENTIFIER_AUTHORITY, // [u8; 6]
    SubAuthority: [DWORD; 1],
}
```

This works when you just have references to it, but if you ever create an owned `Sid` and set the `SubAuthorityCount` to anything other than 1, WinAPI calls will read invalid `SubAuthority` entries.

Option 2: Optimistically allocate the maximum number of `DWORD`s:

```rust
pub struct SID {
    Revision: BYTE,
    SubAuthorityCount: BYTE,
    IdentifierAuthority: SID_IDENTIFIER_AUTHORITY, // [u8; 6]
    SubAuthority: [DWORD; 256],
}
```

This introduces memory overhead (the common case is to have a couple of sub-authorities). It also means that a WinAPI-allocated SID cannot just be cast to the `SID` type, because the additional `SubAuthorities` that Rust expects to be there were not allocated by the SID.

Option 3: Dynamically-sized array:

```rust
pub struct SID {
    Revision: BYTE,
    SubAuthorityCount: BYTE,
    IdentifierAuthority: SID_IDENTIFIER_AUTHORITY, // [u8; 6]
    SubAuthority: [DWORD],
}
```

Now it is no longer `Sized`, which accurately reflects the shape of the underlying memory. Additionally, because `Sized` types cannot be declared directly (I think?), it can only be created using the FFI calls. However, now all pointers to it are automatically fat pointers, which makes it much more difficult to interoperate with the FFI calls, which all expect bare (thin?) pointers.

Option 4: It's never going to be allocated, so just... nothing. It will only ever be handled as a reference, and I will never look at the underlying fields, so there is no reason to expose anything at all:

```rust
pub struct SID {}
```

This feels super strange. I know that zero-sized types have different behavior in Rust than in C, and I feel uncomfortable using them around FFI calls. However, it does reflect the way the `SID` type should be *used*: it should only be by reference (or `Box` or another pointer), and the fields are irrelevant. But I am definitely not certain about the behavior when, for example, casting ZSTs `&`s to raw pointers and back.

Or maybe something else? Currently I am using option 1, keeping everything private, and just not accessing any of the fields directly (everything is through WinAPI calls), but I am curious about which approach people recommend and whether my analysis was correct.

Comment: I'd advise to go the third way, as it is the one most correctly representing the semantics (of course, the price will be an explicit cast on every FFI boundary). But I'm afraid that this question is primarily opinion-based.

Comment: Like @Cerberus said, this is primarily a matter of opinion. That being said I would go with option 4, which is similar to the C/C++ way of declaring just `struct SID;` in the public headers and keeping the full declaration in the source or in a private header.

Comment: I believe your question is answered by the answers of [What's the Rust idiom to define a field pointing to a C opaque pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38315383/155423). If you disagree, please **[edit]** your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Comment: `SID` is not a dynamic sized type, this doesn't exist in C anyway... I agree with shep about the duplicate the doc clearly state "Applications should not modify a SID directly. To create and manipulate a security identifier, use the functions listed in the See Also section." to it should be opaque in Rust too

Comment: FWIW, if it's possible for there to be zero subauthorities, then Option 1 will allow accessing undefined memory (*bad*). If it's possible for there to be less than 256 subauthorities, the Option 2 will allow accessing undefined memory (*bad*). Having a trailing array would be invalid because nothing would ever set up the length of the array properly as the Rust compiler expects it (*bad*). All of those will probably trigger undefined behavior. An opaque struct is the correct choice here.

Comment: @Shepmaster You're right, it is a dupe. I'll go with the approaches in that other question. Also, 0 subauthorities isn't technically allowed, but lots of WinAPI calls are happy to handle (and even allocate!) them.